# How to add DataFrames as columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

****WHEN I USE THE APPEND FUNCTION, ONE DATAFRAME COMES BENEATH THE OTHER BUT I WANT THEM BESIDE EACH OTHER. HOW TO DO THAT? I'm TALKING ABOUT (Colour_Features)** THE OUTPUT IS IN THE IMAGE.**
[image: output]

```
import pandas as pd 

red_data = pd.DataFrame([[255,0,20],[210,30,0],[220,40,5],[240,10,30],[225,60,20]])
green_data = pd.DataFrame([[0,255,0],[10,240,5],[0,240,20],[5,220,30],[30,230,10]])
blue_data = pd.DataFrame([[30,10,220],[10,10,255],[0,0,240],[25,15,210],[0,20,220]])

red_data.columns =["R","G","B"]
green_data.columns =["R","G","B"]
blue_data.columns =["R","G","B"]

print(red_data)
print(green_data)
print(blue_data)


Feature1 = red_data.loc[:,"R"]-red_data.loc[:,"G"]
Feature2 = 2*red_data.loc[:,"B"] - red_data.loc [:,"R"] - red_data.loc [:,"G"]

print(Feature1)
print(Feature2)
Colour_Features= pd.DataFrame([[]])
Colour_Features=Feature1.append(Feature2)
print (Colour_Features)
```

Comment: **WHY** ARE YOU SHOUTING AT US?? Writing in ALL CAPS is both annoyingly hard to read, and generally considered **SHOUTING** at your readers which is just plain rude and offensive - **DON'T DO IT** and fix our post ASAP

Comment: I wrote it in caps to specify my comment and the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the Data Frames along axis 1 (columns).

```
Colour_Features=pd.concat([Feature1, Feature2], axis=1)
print (Colour_Features)

     0    1
0  255 -215
1  180 -240
2  180 -250
3  230 -190
4  165 -245
```